# Is it possible to use Regex Expressions in the NgClass Directive?

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is the row section of my Material Table, I am able to highlight the specified row if I put the exact value after row.name, but what I am trying to do is highlight every row that has the name Rage in it not caring about any characters afterwards, naturally I tried to apply regex expressions.

I have tried to use the ngPattern directive but I could not figure any workable solution

```
   <mat-row  
       *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
        [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowIndex == row.id, 
                    'move_highlight': row.name === 'Rage.*'}">
   </mat-row>
```

I was expecting that after I put the .* after Rage that it would detect every row based off the regex expression but instead it did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a string comparison as you have written it, testing if `row.name` literally equals `'Rage.*'`.

What you really want is:

`/^Rage.*/.test(row.name)`

I'm not sure you can actually drop a regex into Angular HTML like that, however, so what I'd probably do is create a function in your TypeScript class file like this:

```
  testForRage(s: string) {
    return /^Rage.*/.test(s);
  }
```

And then put:

`'move_highlight': testForRage(row.name)}">`

...into your HTML.

Comment: Ty it works perfectly, also I am not sure what the .test does if possible can you explain

Comment: `.test()` is a method provided by regexes to test if a given string matches the regex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test